# Minimum set of axioms for equality

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was reading the Wikipedia article on the axioms of equality [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) and I was a bit surprised by the fact that 3 axioms are provided (reflexivity, substitution for functions and substitution for formulas), but the article seems to imply that the substitution for functions is a sub-case of substitution for formulas.
It even goes as far as proposing which formula should be chosen:
$x = y → (f(...,x,...) = z → f(...,y,...) = z)$
It is easy to deduce commutativity and transitivity, but with these properties and the two supposedly necessary axioms, I was not able to deduce $f(...,x,...)=f(...,y,...)$. Is there a way or I am misunderstanding the Wikipedia article?

I think the question could be reduced to "can I prove that $x=y$ from $(x=z \rightarrow y=z)$ without using the axiom of substitution for functions?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For the sake of readability, I will leave out the "$\dots $" in $f(\dots, x, \dots)$ and instead write $f(x)$)

Since we have $x = y \to f (x) = z \to f (y) = z$ for every $z$, then in particular we have $x = y \to f (x) = f(x) \to f (y) = f(x)$ which gets us $x = y \to f(x) = f(y)$ by symmetry and reflexivity.

Comment: Thanks, all clear.